# Scrollbars on Canvas in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I realize some form of this question has been asked on here as well as in other forums before. I've read through all of them and worked towards those solutions for hours each and I still cant get it. The goal was just a new window (Toplevel) with a scrollable canvas in it that has a frame with some content in it. I still can't get the scroll bars on the canvas to work:

```
        #make new window
        self.edit_window = Tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.edit_window.title("Data Refinement")
        self.edit_window.maxsize(height='50', width='300')

        #make scrollbar for canvas
        cScrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.edit_window)
        cScrollbar.pack(side=Tkconstants.RIGHT, fill=Tkconstants.Y)

        #make canvas
        canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self.edit_window)

        #attach canvas to scrollbar
        canvas.config(yscrollcommand=cScrollbar.set)
        cScrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview) 

        #make frame and put everything in frame
        frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.edit_window)

        #random fill
        Tkinter.Label(frame, text="Enter bounds for the parameters").pack()
        Tkinter.Label(frame, text="Enter bounds for the parameters").pack()
        Tkinter.Label(frame, text="Enter bounds for the parameters").pack()
        Tkinter.Label(frame, text="Enter bounds for the parameters").pack()
        Tkinter.Label(frame, text="Enter bounds for the parameters").pack()
        Tkinter.Label(frame, text="Enter bounds for the parameters").pack()

        #scrollbar for listbox
        scrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(frame)
        scrollbar.pack(side=Tkconstants.RIGHT, fill=Tkconstants.Y)

        listbox = Tkinter.Listbox(frame)
        listbox.pack()

        #insert some random data for now into listbox
        for i in range(100):
            listbox.insert(Tkconstants.END, i)

        # attach listbox to scrollbar
        listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

        #pack and attach to canvas
        frame.pack(fill=Tkconstants.BOTH, expand=Tkconstants.YES)
        canvas.create_window(0,0, anchor = Tkconstants.NW, window = frame)

        canvas.pack(fill=Tkconstants.BOTH, expand=Tkconstants.YES)
        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(Tkconstants.ALL))
```

So the frame is successfully made with the contents. And the frame is successfully attached to the canvas. What I dont get is that the scroll bar attached to the listbox works while the one connected to the canvas displays but does not actually work. The scroll bar acts like everything is already displayed. It's like it is scrolling on what is visible instead of scrolling on the entirety of the contents of the canvas.

Comment: Does anyone see why the way I am doing it works for the listbox but not the canvas? I keep applying examples of scrolling canvases from online but I get the same problem....this is so horribly frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at a computer right now to verify, but my guess is this: the height of the frame will be 1 until the widget is mapped, at which point it will grow or shrink to fit its contents. However, you are setting the canvas scrollregion before this happens so the scroll region is effectively zero. You can verify this by printing out the result of the command `canvas.bbox(Tkconstants.ALL)`

Try adding a call to `self.update_idletasks` before configuring the scroll region and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Awesome, that was it, calling self.edit_window.update_idletasks() fixed it right up.